# Android Maps Extensions gone awry

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-maps-extensions

Ok so I've searched and searched, I'm on the final hurdle of getting this example project working, but now it keeps failing to launch on my phone (Galaxy S4) when I try to implement android-maps-extensions 2.0 (I have loads to markers to add to the map, but need them dynamically)

I have the libraries all setup and working as they should, but whenever I change my MapFragment codes to SupportMapFragment the app crashes and doesn't open. If I leave everything as is the app loads on my phone fine

LogCat

```
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.mypackage/com.me.mypackage.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at com.me.mypackage.MainActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MainActivity.java:102)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at com.me.mypackage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
01-20 12:24:53.382: E/AndroidRuntime(21636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
```

Manifest XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.me.mypackage"
android:id="@+id/theMap"
android:name="com.androidmapsextensions.SupportMapFragment"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


<permission
android:name="com.me.mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.mhmedia.fuelfinder.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/logo"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="myAPI_KEY" />
<activity
android:name="com.me.mypackage.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"></meta-data>
</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationSource {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private OnLocationChangedListener mListener;
private LocationManager locationmanager;
GoogleMap googlemap;
LatLng myposition;
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

if(locationmanager != null){
boolean gpsIsEnabled = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
boolean networkIsEnabled = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

if(gpsIsEnabled){
locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F, this);
}
else if(networkIsEnabled)
{
locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F, this);
}
else
{
Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

setUpMapIfNeeded();
showmypoi();
}

}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
if(locationmanager != null){
locationmanager.removeUpdates(this);
}
super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
setUpMapIfNeeded();
if(locationmanager != null){
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
if (mMap == null){
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getExtendedMap();

if (mMap != null){
setUpMap();
}
mMap.setLocationSource(this);
}

}

private void showmypoi() {
InputStream is = null;
is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.markers);

ArrayList<Entry> entries = (ArrayList<Entry>) new ParserParsing().parse(is);
for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++){
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getExtendedMap();
mMap.setClustering(new ClusteringSettings().enabled(false).addMarkersDynamically(true));
/* mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(lng)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", getPackageName())
} 
}

private void setUpMap() {
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener) {
mListener = listener;


}

@Override
public void deactivate() {
mListener = null;

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {}

public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition){

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
if( mListener != null){
mListener.onLocationChanged( location );

LatLngBounds bounds = this.mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

if(!bounds.contains(new LatLng(location.getAltitude(), location.getLongitude())));{
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));

}

}

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Provider Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Provider Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm wracking my brains trying to figure this out. I have so many markers to add to the map I need the clustering abilities of the map extensions

Thank you

Comment: `mMap` is likely null.

Comment: In what way? Because the app launches fine if MapFragment is used, it crashes when SupportMapFragment is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. I wasn't importing com.androidmapsextensions.SupportMapFragment in my layout file, I was importing com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment hence the map wasn't loading.